# Sending email with camel

Tags: apache-camel

I'm having issues sending an email out through camel with the java dsl.
I've been using the [camel mail](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/mail.html) guide but I receive the following error.

`Caused by: [com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException - Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.google.com, 25; timeout 30000]`

Here is what I have in my route

```
    from("timer://foo?period=5000")  // Create a message every 5 seconds
            .setHeader("subject", simple("hello from camel"))
            .setBody(simple("camel"))
            .log("sending?")
            .to("smtps://smtp.google.com?password=mypass123&username=user@custom.com&From=user@custom.com&To=testuser@gmx.com");
```

The email service is actually provided by gmail. Now I did see a gmail plugin, but its pretty tough to find an example, so I thought I would use the standard method for now. But if someone knows the solution using it, I welcome it!

PS. I have `camel-mail` dependency and the`camel-google-mail` which I'm not using.

Versions 2.20.2

Comment: GMail requires ssl connection. `.to("smtps://smtp.google.com?...` should work

Comment: Thanks, but I get nearly the same `com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException - Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.google.com, 465; timeout 30000`

Comment: Do you use 2 factor authentication on your gmail account? Then you can't simply use your password. And notice that gmail differs between SSL (port 465) and TLS (port 587).

Comment: No 2fa. I did try a different personal gmail account too, and had the same issue.

Comment: Since you receive a timeout after 30 seconds, I assume you don't reach the Gmail server, but the traffic is blocked by something. Have you tried to connect with Telnet or similar tools?

Comment: Seems okay when I type "$ telnet smtp.gmail.com smtp" i get back `Trying 64.233.167.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP k82sm8155051wmf.17 - gsmtp`

Comment: Your to endpoint setting is incorrect. `smtp.google.com` does not exist while `smtp.gmail.com` do exist

Comment: oh true! okay so getting somewhere, now I get `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=657657 > Please log in via your web browser and then try again.` this could be a security issue on gmail side. . .

Comment: I allowed access to Less secure apps in gmail settings but no joy.

Comment: Now login to your account, go to https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click on continue. You had too many invalid connections while testing route and this will supress captcha check

Comment: no luck with that. I can see an email `Review blocked sign-in attempt from less secure app`. So its blocking it, I've tried using the following options mail.smtp.auth=true & mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true and used this https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/1cb67e25a3b59e00864165cff5ea02c3ad356052/components/camel-mail/src/main/docs/mail-component.adoc#using-the-jsse-configuration-utility. However, I wasn't able to complete the registry part as unsure about what its asking.
Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to less secure apps not fully being turned off.

Use this link here https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Also some of the silly mistakes pointed out in the comments.

Thanks!